# Performance of .constant added to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like some thoughts on the performance of using constants in a view; is there a better way? (Bear with me, new to Angular)

I am injecting constants, 'fieldConst,' as a dependency into a controller, like so:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('jobsCtrl', ['$scope', 'jobsService', 'fieldConst', jobsCtrl]);

    function jobsCtrl($scope, jobsService, fieldConst) {

        $scope.fieldConst = fieldConst;

        // get Jobs
        var state = jobsService.getState();
        $scope.jobs = state.jobs;
    }
})();
```

I am using these in my view, like so:

```
... 
<a ng-href="#" ng-repeat="job in jobs.records">
    <h5>{{ job[fieldConst.JOBNUMBER] }} {{ job[fieldConst.JOBTITLE] }}</h5>
    <small ng-switch on="job['isActive']">
...
```

Is this substantially less performant than using, say:

`<h5>{{ job.JobNumber] }} {{ job.jobTitle] }}</h5>`

I have a large number of fields/properties being used across the app, and the names of these as defined in a database, are subject to change; thus the desire to use constants

Comment: sorry but didn't get your issue .

Comment: I'm a little confused. `job.jobTitle` would imply there's a property on job that lets you know its title. `job[fieldConst.JOBTITLE]` implies you're looking up something on job by a title, two different actions.

To your question, lookup up a value by key is so fast that it will not be your limiting factor (though doing a one time binding would be preferable if it's static data).

Comment: job.jobTitle = job[jobTitle] = job[fieldConst.JOBTITLE] to my knowledge. In the last one, fieldConst.JOBTITLE 'returns'  'jobTitle' which is the property on job which I'm after. I was concerned mostly about the use of constants in this way adding additional watchers. I don't want to use one-time binding on the whole expression; using it just on the constant would be good, but I can't see how this can be done, e.g. jon[::fieldConst.JOBTITLE] can't be parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance is the same. Adding a variable to the $scope doesn't create a watcher. What creates a watcher is each {{}}, ng-if, ng-show, etc.
Each {{}} has a expression that needs to be evaluated when the digest cycle runs and what Angular will do is check is that expression changed or not to update the view. 
So in your case the question is if `job.JobNumber` is more performant than `job[fieldConst.JOBNUMBER]`.

So my final answer is FORGET ABOUT IT. Is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your view simple, otherwise it can become black hole which is hard to debug. That's why I personally suggesting to use `job.JobNumber` in your scenario. But you are already have a `jobService` service which should return you whatever you need. Just extend this service by methods `getNumber()` and `getTitle()`. If you are worried about updating the view after data changed outside of angular, you can use functions from view.

controller:

```
$scope.getTitle = function(){ return jobsService.getTitle(); };
$scope.getNumber = function(){ return jobsService.getNumber(); };
$scope.jobs = jobService.getState().jobs;
```

view:

```
<h5>{{jobsCtrl.getTitle()}} {{jobsCtrl.getNumber()}}</h5>
```

Don't worry much about performance (you can't feel difference as a user). If you keep your structure simple and modular, its easier to debug, extend and fixing bugs.

Hope that's help.

Comment: OFC you can return constant value not jobsService.getTitle() if you really want to use constant. But I rather keep all processing in one place, service.